# Fetching library source tarball instead of doing sudo apt get on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am building github.com/dtrace4linux/linux on Ubuntu 12.0.4 X86_64 bit and some of the dependent libraries are fetched by doing a sudo apt-get install. Need to know how I can fetch a dependent library as a source tarball and build/install it instead of using the one fetched by apt-get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some useful links.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
sudo apt-get source --compile <package>
```

is some examples,

and you can more information on following links

https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get